# How to pass multiple images as input to python script

Tags: python, arrays, node.js, performance, multidimensional-array

I use nodejs to call a python script that runs object detection for some jpg images reading from the hard disk. These images are written to the disk by nodejs prior to calling the script.

To make it dynamic and faster, now I want to send multiple images as multidimensional array from nodejs to the python script. This saves me writing and reading images from disk. Is this the best way to do this? If so how do I pass images as multidimensional array to python script? Or Is there any better solution?

Comment: I think pass the path of the images is better than pass multidimensional arrays.

Comment: But writing to harddisk(nodejs) and reading from(python) hard disk should be much slower than reading from ram right? Or is there any other benefit? @stamaimer

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves out a lot of specifics, but if you literally mean "pass input to a python script," you have two options: command line arguments or standard input.

While it is technically possible to read a series of images from standard input, it is certainly more complicated with no benefit to make it worth while.

Command line arguments can only be strings, read from `sys.argv` So, you while you could try to use multiple command line arguments, it would be more trouble than it's worth to translate an array of strings into a multidimensional array.

**So, tl;dr** create a data file format that lets you represent a set of images as a multidimensional array of file paths (or URLs, if you wanted).  The easiest by far would be simply to use a CSV file and read it in with the `csv` Python module.

```
import csv
image_path_array = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv','r')))
```